# MS SQL Server 2017- Merging large tables automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Using Microsoft SQL server 2017, I want to merge two tables into a 3rd table.

Is there a way to have it defined automatically, without a query?

If it is not possible, I would like to mention that both tables contain a large amount of columns, therefore I look for an efficient query that will not make me write each column name.

**Demonstration:**

Original tables are Table1,Table2, column structure is as below:

```
Table1:
(Column1,Column2,Column3)

Table2:
(Column4,Column5,Column6)
```

My goal is to create Table3. Table3 is based on  **Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Column1=Column4**.

```
Table 3:
(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create it as a view.

```
CREATE VIEW table3 AS 
     SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6 
     FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Column1=Column4
```

You can then reference table3 in other queries exactly like an ordinary table.